# Live search with a few JS words entered

Tags: javascript, html

There is such a live search code. Clicking the checkbox adds the word to the line. When writing the necessary words with a space, it works fine and shows lines in which there is one of the inscribed words. How to make it so that when you click on the checkbox it immediately worked, as when you type the word manually?

```
[code]https://codepen.io/dduckker/pen/VOwmJG
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the input with the value of the checkbox the input is joined with a space.

```
function update() {
  document.getElementById('output').value = 
    [...document.querySelectorAll('#content input:checked +  label')]
      .map(label => label.textContent).join(' ');
}
```

This works, however, the input does not get the `keyup` event to filter the actual list:

```
INPUT.addEventListener('keyup', filterList)
```

To solve this, you either need to manually call filterList and anything else you want to do when an input is changed, or you can trigger the event manually.